# Frequent occurrence of FTP Error 550 while trying to access FTP Server

Tags: c#, ftp, azure-functions

I have been working on an azure function. **I am trying to access FTP from the function at every 3 seconds of interval**. Sometimes, I get FTP error 550 while I try to access it.

Here is the code

```
 try
            {
                FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = GetFTPWebRequest(WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory, path);
                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                return streamReader;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
}
```

The frequency of the error is higher sometimes.

What can possibly be the issue here. As the error isn't traced at FTP sometimes.

Can We have some preventive steps here.?

Comment: Does error always occur with same file writing to same location?  Error 550 can occur if you are attempting to write to a location you do not have permission.  Is it possible somebody else is accessing the file?  Does error occur immediately or after a period of time?

Comment: it occurs infrequently